# Проблема с установкой КуМира на Linux

Tags: linux, кумир

В силу определённых обстоятельств, мне нужно установить систему программирования КуМир на OC Linux. КуМир поставляется в виде исходников в tar.gz пакете. Внутри нет ни файла конфигурации ни файлов для его создания. Прошу помощи в этом вопросе или deb пакет(неважно какой версии). Благодарю за каждый ответ.

OC: Debian на KDE.
Ссылка на КуМир: https://www.niisi.ru/kumir/dl.htm

Comment: Омг, он ещё жив?!

Comment: @AlexeyTen к сожалению он есть даже в ОГЭ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [faq](https://www.niisi.ru/kumir/faq.htm) сайта в вопросе

#9 вопрос - ответ:

Предполагается, что специальная системная установка Кумира под Линукс не требуется, достаточно вручную распаковать архив в любую удобную папку, например - в папку kumir2 в домашней пользовательской папке, после чего запускать его либо командами типа
~/kumir2/bin/kumir2-classic
либо с помощью файлового менеджера из подпапки bin той папки, в которую раскрыт Кумир.

При наличии административных прав можно распаковать этот архив в общую папку типа
/usr/local/kumir2
после чего в папке /usr/local/bin создать символические ссылки на требуемые запускаемые файлы Кумира.