# Проблема с установкой КУМИРа на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, установка, кумир

Необходимо было установить КУМИР на систему убунту. Скачали на оф сайте файл которым был исходник в `tar.gz` пакете. Посмотрел это [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100074/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%9c%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux/1100126#1100126) но мне не особо помогло. Переместил скаченый упакованный пакет в папку `snap` где распаковал и попробовал запустить как в том *решении* `/home/kukuruzka-vitya/snap/Kumir2X-59a8c9f1/bin/kumir2-classic` но это просто выдало ошибку `/home/kukuruzka-vitya/snap/Kumir2X-59a8c9f1/bin/kumir2-classic: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` а дальше я не знаю что делать(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ вам сюда
Если с английском плохо - https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ru&op=translate&hl=ru

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с установкой КуМира на Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100074/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%9c%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux)

Comment: Кроме папки bin что то ещё есть?

Comment: Еще есть папки `lib` и `shere` они есть на первом скрине

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688812/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-qt5svg), установил все библиотеки из того списка кроме `qt5-default` и `libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev` и тогда компиляция пошла

```html
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake qt5-default qtscript5-dev libssl-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libsdl2-dev libasound2 libxmu-dev libxi-dev freeglut3-dev libasound2-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libxrandr-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже вылезла ошибка на Ubuntu 20.04.6
при попытке запуска приложения из скачанного с оф. сайта архива
"**error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**"

Я также запустил установку всех пакетов как и топикстартер:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake qt5-default
 qtscript5-dev libssl-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools
 qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev
 libsdl2-dev libasound2 libxmu-dev libxi-dev freeglut3-dev
 libasound2-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libxrandr-dev
 libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5
```

Потом оказалось, что в репозиториях Ubuntu уже недоступен Qt4

Поэтому я склонировал их оф.репозиторий

```
git clone https://git.niisi.ru/kumir/kumir2.git
```

Там в README написано, что можно скомпилировать КуМир с использованием новой версии Qt5, указав дополнительный параметр DUSE_QT:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DUSE_QT=5 ..
```

И в процессе компиляции оказалось, что не хватает одной библиотечки
libqt5x11extras5-dev, я её доустановил:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

Запустил компиляцию:

```
make
```

И она прошла успешно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]